# How do you render a django form in a view?

Tags: django, django-forms

```
for field in FIELDS:
    row = []
    row.append("<tr>")
    row.append("<td>" + str(myform.fields.get(field)) + "</td>")
    row.append("</tr>")

    custom_fields.append("".join(row))
```

When I give the `custom_fields` variable to the template, all I'm getting is:

```
<tr><td><django.forms.widgets.CheckboxInput object at 0x1fa7d90></td></tr>
```

How can I get the form rendered properly?

---

This is what I'm going to be doing eventually:

```
form1 = CustomForm1()
form2 = CustomForm2()
form3 = CustomForm3()

for field in FIELDS:
    row = []
    row.append("<tr>")
    row.append("<td>" + str(form1.fields.get(field)) + "</td>")
    row.append("<td>" + str(form2.fields.get(field)) + "</td>")
    row.append("<td>" + str(form3.fields.get(field)) + "</td>")
    row.append("</tr>")

    custom_fields.append("".join(row))
```

So I can display all form fields together in one table.

Comment: Why on earth are you writing HTML in your view, then passing that to the template? You should do all the HTML generation in the template, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figured this out. It's `form[field]` instead of `form.fields[field]`

```
>>> f = MyForm()
>>> f
<myform.forms.MyForm object at 0x1fa7810>

>>> f['myfield']
<django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x20c7e50>

>>> f.fields['myfield']
<django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0x1fa7850>
```

so `form.fields` is a list of all unbound fields, and `form.__getitem__` is a callable that returns the bound fields.

Answer (score 4):

As [explained here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template), form instances have some predefined rendering methods like `as_table`, `as_ul`, `as_p` that you can use in templates.

`as_table` seems to cut your needs but in case not, you can easily add your custom rendering methods to your own form classes. Having a look at django.forms.forms.BaseForm class is a good idea at this point.

Comment: +1. Django provides an inteface to render your forms for you, so best to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the list of fields to the template by itself? The fields need to be part of an object derived from `forms.Form` in order for the template to render it correctly.

Given that you've got the call to `myform.fields.get()` it looks like you *have* a Form object; what exactly are you trying to do with this list of fields?